# Convert String to a sequence of ints separated with a delimiter using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

So, I have a List of words that consist of autogenerated symbols. For example: `hqst`. I convert each symbol of this word to unicode and concatenate it dividing by dot `.` like this: `104.113.115.116`.

I write the next lambda:

```
.map(word -> {
    char[] symbols = word.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder newWord = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
        newWord.append((int) symbols[i]).append(".");
        if (i == symbols.length - 1) {
            newWord = new StringBuilder(newWord.substring(0, i));
        }
    }
    return newWord.toString();
})
```

Is it possible rewrite this anonymous method using stream API?

Comment: Aren't use already using the `Stream` API? Which `map` method are you passing this lambda expression to?

Comment: As a side note, with `newWord = new StringBuilder(newWord.substring(0, i));` you’ve probably found the most expensive alternative to just saying `newWord.setLength(i);` Further, instead of comparing `i` with `symbols.length - 1`, you could have done `newWord.setLength(Math.max(0, symbols.length - 1);` once *after* the loop. And the whole code would work without copying the entire `String` into a `char[]` array, just using `charAt(i)`…

Comment: Though, after looking at it again, your code does not even look correct, as what you actually want, most likely is `if(newWord.length() > 0) newWord.setLength(newWord.length() - 1);` after the loop, to remove the last `'.'` rather than setting the result string to the length of the original string minus one. So the whole code could be simplified to `.map(word -> { StringBuilder newWord = new StringBuilder(); for( int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) newWord.append((int)word.charAt(i)).append('.'); return newWord.substring(0, Math.max(0, newWord.length()-1)); })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep. You can use [`String::chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#chars()) to get an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) from the word, then map each int to a String and collect with a [joining collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
.map(word -> word.chars()
                 .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                 .collect(Collectors.joining("."))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With assumption the words are stored in list as integer value based on the sample value provided(since you didn't give full code code snippets). I believe it helps.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(104);
    list.add(113);
    list.add(115);
    list.add(116);
   String str =  list.stream().map(word->word.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining( "." ));
   System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: The code is perfectly clear and is presented in full. The word is a string, not a list of integers. In his "hqst" example, **h** becomes 104, **q** becomes 113, **s** becomes 115, and **t** becomes 116.